# Aggregations and the DDD

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, aggregation

I´m developing a project applying the DDD principles, I created a class aggregation (Account) it will contain the classes (Agency) and (Agent) which as (Account) has tables in the database. My question is this:

I need to create a Repository class and a Service class for each of my entities (Account, Agent and Agency) or I should create the AccountRepository and within it do the insertions and searches of the 3 classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only aggregate roots shall have repositories, but you have to come up with the right aggregates.

Without knowing anything about your domain I feel that `Agency` and `Agent` are aggregate roots of their own, so they would each have their repository and `Account` would reference them by identity.

Designing aggregates is the most complex modeling task and entire books could be written on the subject. I strongly recommend you to read [Effective Aggregate Design](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=838) by Vaughn Vernon.

Comment: Great answer and great book.  Whenever I talk to anyone about DDD, I can never stress the same sentiment enough.  Have seen a lot of people fail by treating aggregate design like data modeling, i.e. a single up-front effort which generate a rigid domain model that people are unwilling to change.  The entire domain should grow organically out of use cases and people need to start with the understanding that it /will/ change as part of the ongoing discovery process.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am going to read that book I think it is very important to be clear about these concepts